# Convert uppercase characters back to uppercase after case insensitive regex being applied

Tags: javascript, regex

Here trying to convert uppercase characters back to uppercase after a regex match removes the characters that are uppercase :

```
var text = 'Test Text';
var stringToStyle = 'test';                   
var update = "<span style='color:blue' >" + stringToStyle + "</span>";
var regexp = new RegExp(stringToStyle, 'gi');
var updated = text.replace(regexp, update);

function replaceAt(text , index, character) {
    return text.substr(0, index) + character + text.substr(index+character.length);
}

function getPositionsOfUppercaseChars(text) {
   var p = [];

   var i = text.length;
   while (i--) {
   if(text[i] == text[i].toUpperCase() && text[i].trim() != ''){
     p.push(i)
   }
}
return p;
}

console.log(updated)
var positions = getPositionsOfUppercaseChars(text)
console.log(positions)
```

`var positions` contains the positions of the characters which are to be converted
to uppercase, wo I will loop through that updated text and replace characters that were previously
uppercase. But I will need to add an offset to the positions as [5,0] is not correct.

Update :

updated var should be `<span style='color:blue' >Test</span> Text` instead of

```
<span style='color:blue' >test</span> Text
```

This seems a convulated method of achieving solution, is there  a more elegant way ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/6uO3M8kATQLXvWWVx1Vw?p=preview

Comment: If `<span style='color:blue' >test</span> Text` is the desired output then your code is already doing it, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @gurvinder372 please see question update, I made a typo

Comment: Does it mean I was right in the beginning when I suggested `var update = "<span style='color:blue' >$&</span>";`? See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cojfnbp/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant way to use the found match value in the replacement is by using *backreferences* in the replacement pattern:

```
var update = "<span style='color:blue' >$&</span>";
                                        ^^
```

See a demo:

```js
var text = 'Test Text';
var stringToStyle = 'test';                   
var update = "<span style='color:blue' >$&</span>";
var regexp = new RegExp(stringToStyle, 'gi');
var updated = text.replace(regexp, update);
document.body.innerHTML = updated;
```

The `$&` backreference provides quick access to the whole substring matched with a regex pattern. No need using callbacks or other tricks.

Answer (score 2):

to answer your question, yes - you'll be glad to know there is a more elegant way -

```
var updated = text.replace(regexp, function style(match) { return "<span style='color:blue' >" + match + "</span>"; });
```